# Block all connections to a database db2

Tags: database, command-line, db2

I'm working on logs. I want to reproduce a log in which the application fails to connect to the server.

Currently the commands I'm using are

```
db2 force applications all
```

This closes all the connections and then one by one I deactivate each database using

```
db2 deactivate db "database_name"
```

What happens is that it temporary blocks the connections and after a minute my application is able to create the connection again, due to which I am not able to regenerate the log. Any Ideas how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [QUIESCE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0008635.html).

By default users can connect to a database. It becomes active and internal in-memory data structures are initialized. When the last connection closes, the database becomes inactive. Activating a database puts and leaves them initialized and "ready to use".

Quiescing the database puts them into an administrative state. Regular users cannot connect. You can quiesce a single database or the entire instance. See the docs for some options to manage access to quiesced instances. The following forces all users off the current database and keeps them away:

```
db2 quiesce db immediate
```

If you want to produce a connection error for an app, there are other options. Have you ever tried to connect to a non-estisting port, Db2 not listening on it? Or revoke connect privilege for that user trying to connect.

Comment: Thank you for responding
I tried the command it gives me 

"SQL1024N  A database connection does not exist.  SQLSTATE=08003"

Although my application is connected to the database

Comment: Are you connected to the database when executing the statement? You need an open connection for the db-level command.

Comment: my application is connected to the database. which is generating the logs.

Comment: Are you forcing your own application off?

Comment: Yes, I want to block the application to connect to the database so I can generate the log.

Comment: Your aim "..to reproduce a log in which the application fails to connect"  is unclear. Quiescing the database may not help you with that effort.  Better to focus on the exact error message (or error code, sqlcode, sqlstate) that the application receives when it fails to connect.  This will be in the application error/diagostic file and may also be in the Db2 diagnostic files (e.g. db2diag*.log) .

Comment: I basically want to block all the connections to a database so that any application which is trying to connect to the database fails.

Comment: I agree with @mao regarding the debugging. There are many different reasons why a connection may fail. Blocking is just one of them. Try to connect to a different port and it will give an error. I added that to the response

Comment: In that case, Yes quiesce the database will help you, as will stopping the Db2-instance (as long as it is not multi-tenanted, i.e only contains one database).  Depending on your true aim, the same effect might result if the database does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

There are several testing strategies that can be used, they involve disrupting the network connection between client and server:

- Alter the IP routing table on the client to route the DB2 server address to a non-existent subnet
- Use the connection via a proxy software that can be turned off, there is a special proxy [ToxiProxy](https://github.com/Shopify/toxiproxy), which was designed for the purpose of testing network disruptions
- Pull the Ethernet cable from the client machine, observe then plug it back in (I've done this)

This has the advantage of not disabling the DB2 server for other testing in progress.